# Union subselects querydsl

Tags: java, sql, oracle, union, querydsl

I need optimize a dynamic query. This an example, but it has more filters (BooleanExpression)

```
QTable qtable = QTable.table;

BooleanExpression pSubQueryFilter = qtable.field4.in(List<Long>).and((date != null) ? qtable.field5.goe(date) : null);

BooleanExpression pSubQuery =( ((qtable.field1.eq(string1)) .and(qtable .field2.eq(string2)).and(qtable .field3.eq(Boolean.FALSE)))
.or( (qtable.field1.eq(string2)).and(qtable .field2.eq(string1).and(qtable .field3.eq(Boolean.TRUE))))
).and(pSubQueryFilter);

List<T> list = createQuery(pSubQuery ).list(path);
```

This generates this select, but spend more than 30s in DB because OR clauses. This fields (field1 and field2) have already index in DB.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE

  (field1= 'string1'  AND field2='string2'  AND field3=0)

  OR (field1= 'string2'  AND field2='string1'  AND field3=1 ) 

  AND field4 in (1,2,3,4,5,...)  AND field5 > =SYSDATE-365

  ORDER BY  field5 DESC,  id DESC
```

I optimized this select to 1s in SQL with this result:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE

  id IN ( (SELECT id FROM table WHERE field1= 'string1'  AND field2='string2'  AND field3=0)

  UNION (SELECT id FROM table WHERE field1= 'string2'  AND field2='string1'  AND field3=1 ) )

  AND field4 in (1,2,3,4,5,...)  AND field5 > =SYSDATE-365

  ORDER BY  field5 DESC,  id DESC
```

But in QueryDsl didn't get improve. I did it this way, because Union didn't work.

```
BooleanExpression psubq1 = qtable .field1.eq(string1).and(qtable .field2.eq(string2)).and(qtable .field3.eq(Boolean.FALSE));

BooleanExpression psubq2 = qtable .field1.eq(string2).and(qtable .field2.eq(string1)).and(qtable .field3.eq(Boolean.TRUE));

Expression<?>[] args = { qtable .id};

List<Long> resultids = tableRepository.findAllIds(psubq1, args);

resultids.addAll(tableRepository.findAllIds(psubq2, args));

pSubQuery = qtable .id.in(resultids).and(pSubQueryFilter);
```

Exists any way to do the last sql with Querydsl with one call to DB?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There exist a static method `union` in `com.querydsl.sql.SQLExpressions` to do this. As parameters use subqueries created with `SQLExpressions::select`.

```
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*;
import com.querydsl.sql.DatePart;
import com.querydsl.sql.SQLExpressions;
import com.querydsl.sql.oracle.OracleGrammar;
import com.querydsl.sql.oracle.OracleQuery;
...
OracleQuery query = new OracleQuery<>(con);
query.select(table).from(table).where(
    table.id.in(
        SQLExpressions.union(
            SQLExpressions.select(table.id).from(table)
                .where(table.field1.eq("string1")
                    .and(table.field2.eq("string2"))
                    .and(table.field3.eq(Expressions.FALSE))),
            SQLExpressions.select(table.id)
                .from(table)
                .where(table.field1.eq("string2")
                    .and(table.field2.eq("string1"))
                    .and(table.field3.eq(Expressions.TRUE))))
    )
    .and(table.field4.in(1,2,3,4,5))
    .and(table.field5.goe(
        SQLExpressions.dateadd(DatePart.day, OracleGrammar.sysdate, -365))))
.orderBy(table.field5.desc(), table.id.desc());;
```